# Problems with a PHP property which is an array

Tags: php

I get an "Array to string conversion" error when calling the method below. The line of the error is the only line within the method (the one with the database query).

```
public function setStatus($status) {
    $this->mysqli->query("UPDATE projects SET status='$status' WHERE id='$this->data[id]' LIMIT 1");
}
```

If I modify the method a bit, it works fine:

```
public function setStatus($status) {
    $id = $this->data['id'];
    $this->mysqli->query("UPDATE projects SET status='$status' WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Here's more information about the "data" property:

```
    $result = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM projects WHERE id='123' LIMIT 1");
    $this->data = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: Use curly syntax and also don't forget the quotes for the index!

Answer (score 3):

```
public function setStatus($status) {
    $this->mysqli->query("UPDATE projects SET status='$status' WHERE id='$this->data[id]' LIMIT 1");
}
```

to

```
public function setStatus($status) {
    $this->mysqli->query("UPDATE projects SET status='$status' WHERE id='".$this->data['id']."' LIMIT 1");
}
```

notice at the id field I changed it.